# SQL to generate %, n and N from the datatable

Tags: mysql, sql

I seek your help in generating a summary query result as %, n (numerator), and N (Denominator) out of a variable in the dataset for each underlying category:

e.g: data

| sr.no. | is_healthy |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | yes |
| 2 | no |
| 3 | yes |
| 4 | no |
| 5 | yes |
| 6 | yes |
| 7 | no |
| 8 | yes |
| 9 | no |
| 10 | yes |

I expect the following as a summary result

| is_healthy | % | n | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | 60 | 6 | 10 |
| no | 40 | 4 | 10 |

What could be a possible SQL query to solve this challenge?
Thanks in adavance.

Comment: We are using MySQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`N` is the total count of rows in the table.
`n` is the count of rows matching a value.
`%` is just `n/N*100`.

You can get `n` by using `count(*)` in a grouped query and `N` by using `count(*)` in an ungrouped query. Since you know `N` will be a single row, you can cross-join on it:

```sql
SELECT     is_healthy, cnt, total, cnt / total * 100 AS percent
FROM       (SELECT   is_healthy, COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM     my_table
            GROUP BY is_healthy) grouped
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM   mytable) ungrouped
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). This is really helpful.